# Load dataset from amazon S3 to jupyter notebook on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, jupyter-notebook

I want to try image segmentation with deep learning using AWS. I have my data stored on Amazon S3 and I'd like to access it from a Jupyter Notebook which is running on an Amazon EC2 instance.

I'm planning on using Tensorflow for segmentation, therefore it seemed appropriate to me to use options provided by Tensorflow themselves (https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/s3) as it feels that in the end I want my data to be represented in the format of tf.Dataset. However, it didn't quite work out for me. I've tried the following:

```
filenames = ["s3://path_to_first_image.png", "s3://path_to_second_image.png"]
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
for i in range(2):
    print(sess.run(next_element))
```

I get the following error:

```
OutOfRangeError: End of sequence
 [[Node: IteratorGetNext_6 = IteratorGetNext[output_shapes=[[]], output_types=[DT_STRING], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](OneShotIterator_6)]]
```

I'm quite new to tensorflow and have just recently started trying out some stuff with AWS, so I hope that my mistake is gonna be obvious to someone with more experience. I would greatly appreciate any help or advice! Maybe it's even the wrong way and I'm better off with something like boto3 (also stumbled upon it, but thought that tf would be more appropriate in my case) or something else?

P.S. Tensorflow also recommends to test a setup with the following piece:

```
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
print (file_io.stat('s3://path_to_image.png'))
```

For me this leads to `Object doesn't exist` error, though the object certainly exists and it's being listed among others if I use

```
for obj in s3.Bucket(name=MY_BUCKET_NAME).objects.all():
print(os.path.join(obj.bucket_name, obj.key))
```

I also have my credentials filled in `/.aws/credentials`. What might be the problem here?

Comment: Did you discover a solution? I'm still getting errors on using `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` with s3

Comment: @Roelant Hi! As I have mentioned in the comment section under the answer from Farzan - I decided to move all of my files to the EBS which could be mounted to my EC2 instance and used as a drive so all the files were directly accessible. In the end I didn't figure out how to use data directly from S3 for training, and I'd advise for keeping the data at your server where the code runs as it's gonna be orders of magnitude faster than having to continuously download your data from the cloud server. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer to your question but still something I noticed as to why you can't load data using Tensorflow.

The files in your filenames are `.png` and not in the `.tfrecord` file format which is a binary storage format. So, `tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)` shouldn't work.

I think the following will work. Note: this is for TF2, not sure if it is the same for TF1. A similar example can be found here at TensorFlow's web site [tensorflow example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images)

#### Step 1

Load your files into a TensorFlow dataset with `tf.data.Dataset.list_files`.

`import tensorflow as tf`

`list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(filenames)`

#### Step 2

Make a function that will be applied to each element in the dataset by using `map`; this will use the function on every element in the TF dataset.

```
def process_path(file_path):
    '''reads the path and returns an image.''' 
    # load the raw data from the file as a string
    byteString = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
    # convert the compressed string to a 3D uint8 tensor
    img = tf.image.decode_png(byteString, channels=3)
    return img
```

`dataset = list_ds.map(preprocess_path)`

#### Step 3

Check out the image.

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

`for image in dataset.take(1): plt.imshow(image)`

Answer (score 0):

Directly access S3 data from the Ubuntu Deep Learning instance by

```
cd ~/.aws
aws configure
```

Then update aws key and secret key for the instance, just to make sure. Check awscli version using the command:

```
aws --version
```

Read more on configuration

```
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html
```

You can type in jupyter

```
import pandas as pd
from smart_open import smart_open
import os

aws_key = 'aws_key'
aws_secret = 'aws_secret'

bucket_name = 'my_bucket'
object_key = 'data.csv'

path = 's3://{}:{}@{}/{}'.format(aws_key, aws_secret, bucket_name, object_key)

df = pd.read_csv(smart_open(path))
```

Also, objects stored in the buckets have a unique key value and are retrieved using a HTTP URL address. For example, if an object with a key value

```
/photos/mygarden.jpg
```

is stored in the

```
myawsbucket
```

bucket, then it is addressable using the URL

```
http://myawsbucket.s3.amazonaws.com/photos/mygarden.jpg.
```

If your data is not sensitive, you can use the http option. More details:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AmazonS3.html

You can change the setting of the bucket to public. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the end I decided to go with the EBS system to store and use my data for deep learning